# Regex to validate the comma or space separated values with limit

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex to validate the comma/space separated string (Allowing Alphanumeric and underscore) with the limit in each values to 64 and no of such values to 16.

```
var1,val2, val_3 val4  - valid
val*1, val&2 - Invalid due to illegal character
val1...65,val2, val3 val4 - invalid due to first value has 65 characters
val1,val2, val3 val4,...,val17 - invalid because no of values as more than 16
```

I have created a partial regex but there is some issue which I am not able to figure out.

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z_]{0,64}){1}(([,\s]+)([0-9a-zA-Z_]{0-64})){0,15}$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part `[0-9a-zA-Z_]{0,64}`  of the pattern can also match 0 times so it could also match an empty string.

You can omit `{1}` from the pattern, the notation in the second quantifier should be `{0,64}` instead of `{0-64}`

To get a match only, you can omit all the capture groups, and use a single repeating non capture group.

You might write the pattern as:

```
^\w{1,64}(?:[, \t]+\w{1,64}){0,15}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\w{1,64}` Match 1-64 word characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[, \t]+` Match either a comma, space or tab (or use `[,\s]+`)
  - `\w{1,64}` Match 1-64 word characters
- `){0,15}` Close the non capture group and repeat 0 - 15 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tiPgsv/1)

Note that `\s` can also match a newline, so you could also use `[,\s]+`

Comment: Thanks buddy, This works for me and thanks again for the explanation. If you can answer, why we are using non-capturing group. why not just a plain capturing group `{}` ? As I saw the searched it is to ignore the string but what does it do in this place where we not looking for groups.

Comment: @kushalagrawal You can use capture groups, and the match will still work, but you don't need the capture groups for a match only. The engine will remember the group values but they are not being used afterwards for lets say a replacement or accessing the individual group values.